# stack array implementation in C - understanding pass by reference

Tags: c, stack, pass-by-reference

So this is a very simple stack implementation (it's array with just the barebones push pop functions). I'm trying to understand why my index doesn't change after pushing values onto the array. I originally had the itop variable located within the main as "int itop = 0" but since the itop value remained at 0, I thought maybe it was an issue of pass-by-reference where C takes a copy of the value and doesn't actually change the value itself being passed in. So I thought okay I would make it a static int at the top (I know this isn't best practice because of unsafe thread behavior...) but it still wouldn't work.

Anyone point me to understanding this basic concept? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

void push(int a[], int, int);
int pop(int a[], int);

static int itop = 0;

int main(void){
        int stack[100];
        push(stack, itop, 1);
        push(stack, itop, 2);
        printf("index is %d\n", itop);
        int p1 = pop(stack, itop);
        printf("index is %d\n", itop);
        int p2 = pop(stack, itop);
        int p3 = pop(stack, itop);
        printf("popped elements: %d %d %d\n", p1, p2, p3);
        return 0;
}

void push(int a[], int ind, int elem){
        a[ind++] = elem;
}

int pop(int a[], int ind){
        if (ind < 0){
                return -1;
        }
        else {
                return a[ind--];
        }
}
```

Comment: `ind` needs to be a reference for changes made within the function to be visible outside, so `int* ind` in the function headers.

Comment: _I know this isn't best practice because of unsafe thread behavior..._: actually it is just bad design.

Comment: ... and `int itop = 0;` should be declared right after or beforen `int stack[100];`, and without static. There is no reason for `itop` to be global or static.

Comment: The `stack` and `itop` variables are part of the same abstract data structure, so having one of them inside the function and one of them outside the function is bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the variable `itop` by reference. You are passing it by value. The both functions deal with a copy of the variable itop, So changing a copy does not influence on the original object.

Passing by reference in C means passing an object indirectly through a pointer.

Also the function pop has bugs in  these statements

```
if (ind < 0){
    ^^^^^^^
```

and

```
return a[ind--];
         ^^^^^
```

The functions can be declared and defined the following way

```
void push(int a[], int *ind, int elem){
        a[( *ind )++] = elem;
}

int pop(int a[], int *ind){
        if (*ind == 0){
                return -1;
        }
        else {
                return a[--*ind];
        }
}
```

Pay attention to that in general the function pop has a drawback not allowing to store -1 in the stack because the returned value -1 from the function is ambiguous and can mean either an error or an actual element of the stack.

The function could be defined the following way

```
int pop( int a[], int *ind, int *value )
{
    int error = *ind == 0 ? -1 : 0;

    if ( error == 0 )
    {
        *value = a[--*ind];
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: when I use "a[*(ind)++] = elem" the index doesn't update but when I write "a[*ind] = elem; *ind = *ind + 1; " it does which is strange because in the pop() the "a[--*ind]" appropriately

Comment: @user6461080 This expression a[*(ind)++] is invalid. See my code.

Answer (score 1):

In C arguments are passed by value. Therefore this is wrong:

```
void push(int a[], int ind, int elem){
        a[ind++] = elem;   // ind is a local variable here 
                           // modifying it won't have any effect outside
                           // the push function
}
...
push(foo, bar, elem);    // bar won't be modified
```

You want this:

```
void push(int a[], int *ind, int elem){
        a[(*ind)++] = elem;
}
...
push(foo, &bar, elem);   // you pass a pointer to bar
                         // and bar will be modified
```

The same principle needs to be applied with `pop`.

This is most basic C knowledge.

Comment: Aside: "parameters are passed by value" seems incorrect with `push(stack, itop, 1);`  as from the caller's point-of-view, the array `stack` is modifiable by `push()`.  Yes there is the sneaky in-between conversion of the array to the address of it first element - and so back to pass by value, but that is how the function sees `a`, as a pointer. `main:stack` sees it as a pass by reference.   IAC, "parameters are passed by value" is better as "arguments are passed by value" `.   "parameter" is what is received.